# Adding Agreements to a Program

Tags: java

I have an entity named `Program`. `Program` can have a collection of `Agreement`s. I want to add agreement one by one.

The following method takes a `programId` and an `Agreement` itself. And then first find the program by id. If program is found, it then finds the agreement from the database. If agreement is found in the database, it adds the agreement to the program, and return the list of agreements those are added to the program, Otherwise it just return an empty set.

I would like to know a better approach.

```
@Override
public Set<Agreement> addAgreementToProgram(Long programId, Agreement agreement) {

    return programRepository.findOneById(programId)
            .map(program -> agreementRepository.findOneById(agreement.getId()).map(agreementFromDb -> {
                program.getAgreements().add(agreementFromDb);

                return programRepository.save(program)
                        .getAgreements()
                        .stream()
                        .sorted((a, b) -> Long.compare(a.getId(), b.getId()))
                        .collect(Collectors.<Agreement>toSet());
            }).orElse(Collections.emptySet())).orElse(Collections.emptySet());
}
```

Comment: Please state only the code purpose in the title

Comment: @Vogel612 , can you suggest anything? Could you please look through the code and suggest me something?

Comment: Also, your `map(program -> agreementRepository...` part onwards have compilation errors, please update your code too.

Comment: @h.j.k. its java 8

Comment: I know it's Java 8, but the part is still wrong. Is there a copy-paste error somewhere?

Comment: @h.j.k. just copied and pasted form IDE. it works fine .

Comment: The problem is that it looks like your first `map()` on the `Program` is not what you think it's doing... Furthermore, having to chain two `orElse()` statements itself will be another syntax error... nowhere in your code indicates you have an `Optional`, much less two. Besides, if there is an empty `List` of `Agreement`s, doing a `collect()` on its stream will already give you an empty `Set`. Please review your question once again. thanks.

Comment: @h.j.k. `orElses` are not chained. `findOneById` should be returning `Optional`, etc etc. It probably is compiling, but It's a *student code*.

@rokonoid -1 for insufficient explanation and background to compile and refactor the given code snippet.

Comment: @abuzittingillifirca hmms have provided an answer in view of your comment. I guess I wasn't mocking correctly the first time round...

Comment: *return the list of agreements those are added to the program* Why does it return anything?

Answer (score 1):

Decided to take another look after [@abuzittin gillifirca's](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/93854/adding-agreements-to-a-program?noredirect=1#comment174255_93854) comment, and yeah, looks like I went wrong somewhere in my original evaluation.

Although I still agree with the part that there's insufficient explanation, I am offering some inputs below to the best I can mock out your custom classes.

Parts that I have to mock (ignore the formatting, I'm trying to keep these as compact as possible):

```
public static interface Agreement { Long getId(); }

public static interface Program {
    // Using a List for mocking, is this actually a Set? See below...
    default List<Agreement> getAgreements() { return Collections.emptyList(); }
}

public static interface Repository<T> {
    default Optional<T> findOneById(Long id) { return Optional.empty(); }
    default T save(T obj) { return obj; }
}

private Repository<Agreement> agreementRepository = new Repository<Agreement>() {};
private Repository<Program> programRepository = new Repository<Program>() {};
```

`Collectors.toSet()` uses a `HashSet` as the backing implementation, so sorting your `Stream` and then trying to collect into a `Set` will not work as you expected. Instead, you'll need your own `Supplier<Set<Agreement>` as such:

```
private static final Supplier<Set<Agreement>> supplier =
            () -> new TreeSet<Agreement>(Comparator.comparing(Agreement::getId));
```

[`Comparator.comparing(Function)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-) is the more Java 8-friendly way of representing `(a, b) -> Long.compare(a.getId(), b.getId())`.

After reformatting your code (the 'chained' `Optional`, which was tripping me up) and putting in the above changes...

```
public Set<Agreement> addAgreementToProgram(Long programId, Agreement agreement) {
    return programRepository.findOneById(programId)
        .map(program -> agreementRepository.findOneById(agreement.getId())
            .map(agreementFromDb -> { program.getAgreements().add(agreementFromDb);
                return programRepository.save(program).getAgreements().stream()
                        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(supplier));
            }).orElse(Collections.emptySet()))
        .orElse(Collections.emptySet());
}
```

Does `Program.getAgreements()` return a `Set` as well? If so, could you not simply `return` that after calling `programRepository.save(program)`?

**edit**: Just curious, how useful is it to return an empty `Set()` if either the `Program` or `Agreement` cannot be found? I feel like the larger context is required here... Will `addAgreementToProgram().isEmpty()` be used to check whether the addition/persistence is successful, or what?